# Azure Function via terraform azurerm_function_app_function throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-functions, terraform-provider-azure

We've created an Azure Function using [Terraform resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/3.0.2/docs/resources/function_app_function) `azurerm_function_app_function`

Terraform code

- Terraform v1.1.0
- Provider azurerm 3.0.2

```
resource "azurerm_function_app_function" "default" {
  name            = "MyAzureFunction"
  function_app_id = azurerm_linux_function_app.default.id
  language        = "Java"

  file {
    name    = "my-java-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
    content = filebase64("my-java-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar")
  }

  config_json = jsonencode({
    "scriptFile" : "my-java-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar",
    "entryPoint" : "com.mypackage.MyClass.runEvent",
    "bindings" : [
      {
        "type" : "eventGridTrigger",
        "direction" : "in",
        "name" : "eventGridEvent"
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

Java Code

```
package com.mypackage;

import com.microsoft.azure.functions.ExecutionContext;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.EventGridTrigger;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.FunctionName;

public class MyClass {

    @FunctionName("MyAzureFunction")
    public void runEvent(@EventGridTrigger(name = "eventGridEvent") String event, final ExecutionContext context) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java Event Grid trigger function executed.");
        context.getLogger().info(event);
    }
}
```

But unfortunately we are facing the ClassNotFoundException exception:

```
Result: Failure Exception: ClassNotFoundException: com.mypackage.MyClass Stack: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mypackage.MyClass
java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.EnhancedJavaMethodExecutorImpl.getContainingClass(EnhancedJavaMethodExecutorImpl.java:63)
com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.EnhancedJavaMethodExecutorImpl.<init>(EnhancedJavaMethodExecutorImpl.java:22)
com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.FactoryJavaMethodExecutor.getJavaMethodExecutor(FactoryJavaMethodExecutor.java:20)
com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaFunctionBroker.loadMethod(JavaFunctionBroker.java:35)
com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.FunctionLoadRequestHandler.execute(FunctionLoadRequestHandler.java:27)
com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.FunctionLoadRequestHandler.execute(FunctionLoadRequestHandler.java:9)
com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.MessageHandler.handle(MessageHandler.java:45)
com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.JavaWorkerClient$StreamingMessagePeer.lambda$onNext$0(JavaWorkerClient.java:92)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is pretty much no documentation on how to deploy java functions despite using the maven plugin or the func CLI. At the official azure docs they mention that it's possible to upload a ZIP containing the java binaries, libs, configs, etc. - but it's documented to be used with a HTTP call to some exotic API.

In the end I dug into the sources of maven plugin to find out how the deployment happens. Since we currently deploy via func with the help of a `null_resource`, I didn't finished the research of how to use terraform only deployments. I dug into the maven plugin sources for function deployment and stopped here: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/blob/b260278dff807794f2d7e2781a6fd4d212337ab0/azure-toolkit-libs/azure-toolkit-appservice-lib/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/toolkit/lib/appservice/function/FunctionAppBase.java#L55. This reveals that the complete directory content under `target/azure-functions/<project_name>` will be zipped, uploaded to the storage account of the function and some properties at the function app will be set, in specific `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE`.

I suggest that you package the function app with the maven plugin, deploy it either with the plugin or the function core tools and inspect the state of the functions app cloud resource at azure portal to reverse engineer what the official azure docs are missing.